# Accessibility of external links on a webpage?

Tags: html, accessibility, w3c

I've been searching for clear guidelines about how(or even if) you should present external links in an html document in order to conform with any accessibility/usability guidelines. But I can't really find anything.

We have a client that insists that any external links(including menus/navs) should have an icon indicating that it is external.

My question is - is this necessary? What are the minimum requirements for distinguishing external links? Does there need to be a visual clue or is it possible to just indicate in the link title, or name, that if clicked it will go to another website?

Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated as I'm struggling to advise what we should do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distinction between external and internal links is often made by web site owners and managers, but its relevance to users is questionable. [WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/) expresses many concerns about links: [Guideline 2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/#navigation-mechanisms) Navigable: Provide ways to help users navigate, find content, and determine where they are. But external vs. internal is not among them.

The key issue is that the meaning and purpose of each link be available to the user. This is far more important than flagging external links, and such flagging tends to create problems rather than solve any. Flagging might be required by the site owner as a policy and caution matter, but this should not be confused with accessibility.

Comment: Many thanks for the replay. I thought this might be the case.

Comment: +1 - ideally, with well-worded links, the user - sighted or not - will know what to expect from context.

Answer (score 0):

All web browsers will display the link's URL in the status bar when the link is focused or the user has hovered over the link.  As long as you aren't hiding the link's destination URL, the URL in the status bar is good clue of whether the link is external or not.

In the old days of the Internet (10 or 15 years ago) it was common practice to have an exit disclaimer on all external links.  As people have become more comfortable with the concept of linking, there are fewer exit disclaimers on the Web now.  You can expect your users to understand that links with URLs on different sites will take them to a different site.

As for accessibility, screenreaders also provide a way for users to hear the link's URL:

- in Voiceover, pressing Ctrl-Option-Shift+U will read the link's URL.
- in ChromeVox, the command is Ctrl-Alt-U.

Make sure your links display the correct URLs on hover.  You don't need to do anything special in this regard to make your links more accessible.